# Parsing Around Unreadable Characters

Tags: python, parsing, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to parse an API response however the response data contains characters that are giving python some trouble.

API Response: `electricity price | 19.52¢/kW·h (January 1, 2014) natural gas price | $11.05 per thousand cubic feet (January 15, 2014) heating oil price | $4.338/gal (March 17, 2014) propane price | $3.968/gal (March 17, 2014)`

The error is raised at the "cents per kilowatt hour" characters.

Full Error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa2' in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)`

Response as it appears in terminal: `electricity price | 19.52\xa2/kW\xb7h  (January 1, 2014)\nnatural gas price | $11.05 per thousand cubic feet  (January 15, 2014)\nheating oil price | $4.338/gal  (March 17, 2014)\npropane price | $3.968/gal  (March 17, 2014)`

How would I go about parsing the data around these problem characters? I don't need the full text, just the numerical values within it. Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

The code causing the error:

```
search('electricity price | {:d}', energy)
```

I also tried:

```
search('electricity price | {:f}', energy)
```

Which had a similar result. `energy` is a variable storing the full string listed above.

EDIT 2:

Full code including API call:

```
client = wolframalpha.Client('apikey')
energy_query = 'utilities prices in ' + city + ' ' + state_abbr
res = client.query(energy_query)


energy = (next(res.results).text)

search('electricity price | {:d}', energy)
```

Full traceback:

```
File "/Users/aaronpardes/Dropbox/Python/nuLife2/newlifenv/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/aaronpardes/Dropbox/Python/nuLife2/newlifenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/Users/aaronpardes/Dropbox/Python/nuLife2/newlifenv/lib/python2.7/site- packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/aaronpardes/Dropbox/Python/nuLife2/newlifenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/aaronpardes/Dropbox/Python/nuLife2/newlifenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Users/aaronpardes/Dropbox/Python/nuLife2/newlifenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/aaronpardes/Dropbox/Python/nuLife2/newlifenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Users/aaronpardes/Dropbox/Python/nuLife2/newlifenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/aaronpardes/Dropbox/Python/nuLife2/nulife.py", line 120, in index
search('electricity price | {:d}', energy)
File "/Users/aaronpardes/Dropbox/Python/nuLife2/newlifenv/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/parse.py", line 1041, in search
return Parser(format, extra_types=extra_types).search(string, pos, endpos)
File "/Users/aaronpardes/Dropbox/Python/nuLife2/newlifenv/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/parse.py", line 678, in search
return self._generate_result(m)
File "/Users/aaronpardes/Dropbox/Python/nuLife2/newlifenv/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/parse.py", line 699, in _generate_result
fixed_fields[n] = self._type_conversions[n](fixed_fields[n], m)
File "/Users/aaronpardes/Dropbox/Python/nuLife2/newlifenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/parse.py", line 375, in f
if string[0] == '-':
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: What code are you using that generates that error?

Comment: Also, which Python version are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.5 and I have included the code causing the error in my original question.

Comment: `energy` is **already** unicode; what happens that in order to decode `energy`, Python first *encodes* it to a byte string so it can then re-decode, using the default ASCII codec. You don't need to decode here at all.

Comment: It is the `search` call that mixes a byte string and a unicode value, triggering another implicit encode.

Comment: Please undo the `.decode()` calls and give us your original traceback. If `search()` is your own code, I'd love to see the code for that too. If it is from a Python library, what library is that?

Comment: I have removed both decodes and included the original traceback. search() is part of the parse library. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse

Comment: your new exception has nothing to do with Unicode. That's the `parse()` module not handling the given input very well.

Comment: I'd say this is a bug in the `parse()` library; it **probably** won't handle Unicode either (as they build a normal regex without taking Unicode into account), but this is, as it stands, **not** a Unicode problem.

Comment: Could you recommend an alternative route to get the numerical data from the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`energy` is *already* a Unicode object; trying to call `.decode()` on it triggers an implict *encode* first (using ASCII, the default codec):

```
>>> energy = u'19.52¢/kW·h'
>>> energy.decode('windows-1252')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa2' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Notice the exception; decoding a Unicode string triggered a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

This is as designed, the [`wolframalpha` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wolframalpha) uses ElementTree to parse the XML response, which always gives you Unicode objects.

After your update, I took a look over the [`parse` library source code](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse/blob/master/parse.py) I fear you found a bug in the code; they don't escape regular expression metacharacters in the literal strings you hand in. If you **escape** the `|` character it works:

```
>>> search('electricity price \\| {:f}', u'electricity price | 19.52¢/kW·h')
<Result (19.52,) {}>
```

I've opened a [bug report](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse/issues/22) with the `parse` project about this.

Do note that the library is probably limited to parsing ASCII text only; don't try to match the `¢/kW·h` as word characters, at least.

*Update*: [`parse` version 1.6.4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse/1.6.4) has been released fixing this specific bug.

Comment: Pretty sure that's the real solution. Removing my "guesswork" answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue persists.

Comment: @haye321: yes, because you have hardly given me the time to actually investigate the real problem, which is that the library you are using is not up to the task.

Comment: I don't believe I have been rushing you in anyway. I have graciously accepted your help. I'm not sure why you are taking such a demeaning attitude towards the situation.

Comment: @haye321: Sorry, no irritation intended, I see how that comment could have come over as such. I've found a work-around for you, it is the `|` pipe symbol that the library trips over.

Comment: I apologize if this should be obvious but I don't fully understand your workaround. The `|` pipe is directly adjacent to the value I am trying to retrieve. Would that not make this an impassible caveat?

Comment: @haye321: I'm not following you; I showed you the code with the pipe replaced by `\\|` works as the regular expression that `parse.search()` generates then has the character correctly escaped.

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely missed that you had updated your answer. Thanks that did the trick!